# Please help me to solve this problem!! I'm getting Axis error

Tags: python, numpy

**Python**
here i'm getting an error for axis while getting the confusion matrix. The whole code segment is given below.

```
y_val_class = np.argmax(y_val_class, axis=1)
predictions = model.predict(x_val)
y_pred_class = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

cm=confusion_matrix(y_val_class, y_pred_class)

index = ['neutral', 'calm', 'happy', 'sad', 'angry', 'fearful', 'disgust', 'surprised']  
columns = ['neutral', 'calm', 'happy', 'sad', 'angry', 'fearful', 'disgust', 'surprised']  
 
cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm,index,columns)                      
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.axes()

sns.heatmap(cm_df, ax = ax, cmap = 'PuBu', fmt="d", annot=True)
ax.set_ylabel('True emotion')
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted emotion')
```

**The Error**
here I"m not able to understand the axis 1 thing.

```
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6778bcbfa35d> in <module>()
      1 # Validation Confusion matrix
      2 
----> 3 y_val_class = np.argmax(y_val_class, 1)
      4 predictions = model.predict(x_val)
      5 y_pred_class = np.argmax(predictions, 1)

<__array_function__ internals> in argmax(*args, **kwargs)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 
     57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     59     except TypeError:
     60         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: It just means you have a one dimensional array therefore you can't use axis. Probably in some other piece of code you overwrote `y_val_class` or you should not use axis at all

Comment: how can i make the array multi dimentional? @alparslanmimaroğlu

Comment: It depends on the use case. You can just use `np.reshape(arr, (1, -1))` but that might not solve the problem. You should understand why there is an axis=1 in that piece of code and why you don't have a 2d array

Comment: Please amend the title of your post to be focused on your problem. For example: "Numpy AxisError: Axis out of bounds”. Everyone on this website seeks help.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about `y_val_class` and why you specify `axis=1`.  How much of this code is your own, or is it copied from some tutorial or other source?